# Simple ifelse statement in dplyr/tidyquant xts

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyquant

I am trying to create a simple `ifelse` statement using `tidyquant` or `dplyr`.

What I currently have is;

```
from <- "2017-07-09"
to <- "2018-12-01"
getSymbols("GOOG", from = from, to = to, src = "yahoo", adjust = TRUE)

colnames(GOOG) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)

GOOG %>%
  mutate(Direction = ifelse(Close < Open, 1, 0))
```

Which returns an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"
```

I know the `tidyquant` package can use `dplyr` functions on `xts` data so I am also trying to use the `tidyquant` to get around this issue.

The following works but takes the data out of the `xts` format.

```
x <- GOOG %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(Direction = ifelse(Close < Open, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not about `ifelse`. It is about `mutate` and the fact that

```
class(GOOG)
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

In this case you wouldn't really gain anything from `mutate` anyway, so you could just use

```
GOOG$Direction <- with(GOOG, ifelse(Close < Open, 1, 0))
```

However, you could also use `tidyquant` instead of `quantmod` with `getSymbols`:

```
GOOG <- tq_get("GOOG", from = from, to = to)
GOOG %>% mutate(Direction = ifelse(close < open, 1, 0))
# A tibble: 354 x 8
#   date        open  high   low close  volume adjusted Direction
#   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 2017-07-10  922.  930.  920.  929. 1192800     929.         0
# 2 2017-07-11  930.  931.  922   930. 1113200     930.         0
# 3 2017-07-12  939.  946.  934.  944. 1532100     944.         0
# ... with 351 more rows
```

This then works because

```
class(GOOG)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Yet another option would be to keep using `quantmod` but to replace `mutate` by `transform`:

```
GOOG %>% transform(Direction = ifelse(Close < Open, 1, 0))
```

Comment: This works great, any reason why `quantmod` / `xts` doesn´t accept the `ifelse` statement and `tidyquant` does? - `tidyquant` is not `xts` format right?

Comment: @user113156, added a comment about that to my answer.

Comment: @user113156, added yet another option.